# Add a success notification for an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The site has a button to remove the device from the shopping cart.

The principle of the button is as follows:

1. the user clicks the delete button;
2. a window opens (something like a modal window made using Dialog mui) with a warning about the danger of deletion and two buttons: cancel and confirm;

   2a) when you click the cancel button, the window closes;

   2b), when the confirmation button is pressed, the deletion process begins, which is accompanied by a scroll wheel. After deletion, the window closes and the user can continue working on the site.

I would like, after closing the window, to display a notification for a few seconds that the item was successfully deleted. The whole difficulty lies in the fact that there is no fixed deletion time (the deletion time is different depending on the amount of information about the device) and it is not clear to me when the notification window should be called.

Help to understand please.

Here is my short working code

```
export function Delete() {
  const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);
  const [alertLoading, setAlertLoading] = useState(false);

  const onNo = () => {
    setAlertShown(false);
  };

  const onYes = async () => {
      setAlertLoading(true);
      await deleteItem();
      setAlertShown(false);
      setAlertLoading(false);
  };

  
  return <ButtonGroup >
            <div onClick={() => setAlertShown(true)}>
                  <DeleteForeverIcon/>
            </div>

            {alertShown && (
                <Dialog open={onYes}>

                    {alertLoading 
                        ? <div ><Spinner/></div>
        
                        : <DialogActions >
                            <Button   onClick={onNo}>Cancel</Button >
                            <Button   onClick={onYes}>Confirm </Button >
                          </DialogActions>}                   
                </Dialog>
                )}
    </ButtonGroup>
}
```

Here, for a better understanding, I demonstrate a demo version of what I have going on at the moment. The code in the codeSandbox is slightly different from the code I showed above. But the principle is the same. I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Please save the code and share it in sandbox, thanks  :)

Comment: You should display the banner at the same time the modal closes. So what is cloing the modal? In most situations, this is some response from the backend. So the frontend is waiting for a response from the backend. When it gets the response that the data was deleted successfully, it closes the modal. That is exactly what you should use to display the banner.

Comment: @LeeMorgan The modal closes either the Cancel Action button (which is done with setAlertShown(false)), or the modal closes automatically after the delete process, again with setAlertShown(false), which is part of onYes

Comment: Ok, so use that to trigger the banner. When setAlertShown is called, call the function to display your banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added some basic things on what you can do here:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const sleep = (ms = 1000) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

async function deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams) {
  await deleteRecord(firestore, item.id);
}

async function deleteRecord(firestore, recordId) {
  await firestore.collection("records").doc(recordId).delete();
}

const firestoreDummy = {
  collection: () => ({
    doc: () => ({
      delete: async () => {
        // Simulating delete action on firestore
        await sleep(randomIntFromInterval(3000, 10000));
      }
    })
  })
};

const Dialog = ({ loading, onYes, onNo }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: 16 }}>
        <h4>Are you sure</h4>
        <p>Do you really want to delete this item?</p>
        {loading && (
          <div style={{ marginBottom: "8px" }}>
            <span style={{ fontSize: "12px", color: "gray" }}>
              Item is being deleted. Please wait...
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
        <button disabled={loading} onClick={onYes}>
          Yes
        </button>
        <button disabled={loading} onClick={onNo}>
          No
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const SuccessDialog = ({ setSuccessAlertShown }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: 16 }}>
        <h4>Sucessfully deleted!</h4>

        <button onClick={() => setSuccessAlertShown(false)}>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);
  const [alertLoading, setAlertLoading] = useState(false);
  const [alertSucess, setSuccessAlertShown] = useState(false);

  const onNo = () => {
    setAlertShown(false);
  };

  const onYes = async () => {
    setAlertLoading(true);

    try {
      await deleteItem({}, firestoreDummy);
      setAlertShown(false);
    } finally {
      setAlertLoading(false);
      // A simple notification
      alert("The record deleted!");
      // A more classic notification
      setSuccessAlertShown(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setAlertShown(true)}>Delete item</button>
      {alertShown && (
        <Dialog onNo={onNo} onYes={onYes} loading={alertLoading} />
      )}
      {alertSucess && (
        <SuccessDialog setSuccessAlertShown={setSuccessAlertShown} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hill-r8sh1x

Comment: Thank you for bringing my question to my attention, but could you still provide an answer based on the code in the question.

Comment: It could be like this: 1- define a new state like "successAlarmShown" 2- set it to be true when user calls the "onYes" function 3- Do the same way for "successAlarmShown" just like you did with "alarmShown".

Comment: I tried to do it this way, it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Can make the exact code you have in the sandbox please?

Comment: problem next if I use await deleteItem({}, firestoreDummy) - everything works fine, but if I use await deleteItem( item, firestore, urlParams) in my working code - then the notification popup does not appear

Comment: You should use { when you are passing data to components, or you can use "params" and treat it as an object like: params.item

Comment: Tell me how I should change the code so that everything works correctly?